# How to find the maximum number of points lying on the same straight line

Tags: java, algorithm, plane

Suppose you have an array of Points on a 2D plane. Point being defined as such:

```
class Point {
    public int x; 
    public int y;

    Point(int _x, int _y) { x = _x; y = _y; }
}
```

How could I find the maximum number of points lying on the same straight line in java?

Comment: Not possible to solve in less than o(n^2)

Comment: @user3530447 are we talking about a set of arbitrary points here?  Any required time complexity? If you take two points, these two points will always appear in the same line, your next step is to see if other points 'lie' on this line.  You do this for all pair of points.  This is slow (i think its O(n^2))

Comment: The points are on a 2D plane.

Comment: @user3503447 what about time complexity?

Comment: @GaryTsui Yes can't be done in less than O(n^2)

Comment: I'm guessing that with some cleverness you could get it down to n*log n or so.  Not with a straight-forward algorithm, though.

Comment: @TejasPatel Can you prove that?

Answer (score 3):

For each point in the array, calculate the angle between this point and other points. Counting the number of those with the same angle using a hashMap. Expected time O(n^2)

Pseudo code

```
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    HashMap<Double, Integer> map = new HashMap();
    for(int j = 0; j < data.length; j++){
        if(i == j)
            continue;
        double angle = calculateAngle(data[i], data[j]);
        if(map.containsKey(slope)){
            map.put(angle, map.get(slope) + 1);
        }else{
            map.put(angle, 1);
        }
        result = max(result, map.get(slope));
    }
}
```

Note: As mention in NiklasB 's comment, using double will cause some problems with precision, especially when we need to compare those floating values. We can avoid that by using the Rational class suggested by NiklasB. (Or less precise, using [this](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/blog/?p=89))

Comment: Ahm this will surely fail because floating point is not precise. You will have to store some normalized integer fraction. Also you need to be able to handle the case where more than two points have the same x coordinate. In that case the slope is infinity.

Comment: How about parallel lines. will fail for it too

Comment: @TejasPatel parallel lines? this is the slope from one point as origin to other points, not with the Ox or Oy axis :)

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes, infinity case should be handle here, for the floating, we can use BigDecimal instead of double

Comment: @PhamTrung No, BigDecimal can't represent rational numbers

Comment: @NiklasB. uhm agree, will need to handle some tricky cases here, as expected from a geometry problem :)

Comment: I think you will be fine if you just have a `Rational` class that represents a rational number from the set Q extended by +/- infinity (e.g. represented as `+/- (1/0)`). You obviously don't need to include that into your answer, but you should mention that double is insufficient

Comment: The solution in its current version is wrong not only because it uses floating point numbers, but more importanly because it doesn't take into accout points with same coordinates as point `i` and doesn't count point `i` itself.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution in Java using precise arithmetic:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Solver {
    public int maxPointsOnLine(List<Point> points) {
        int ans = 0;
        Map<Line, Integer> lines = new HashMap<Line, Integer>();
        for (Point a : points) {
            int max = 0;
            int same = 0;
            lines.clear();

            for (Point b : points) {
                if (a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y) {
                    ++same;
                } else {
                    Line line = new Line(b.x - a.x, b.y - a.y);
                    Integer count = lines.get(line);
                    if (count == null) {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    ++count;
                    lines.put(line, count);
                    max = Math.max(max, count);
                }
            }
            ans = Math.max(ans, same + max);
        }
        return ans;
    }

    static class Line {
        final int dx;
        final int dy;

        Line(int dx, int dy) {
            if (dy == 0) {
                dx = Math.abs(dx);
            }
            else if (dy < 0) {
                dx = -dx;
                dy = -dy;
            }
            int gcd = gcd(Math.abs(dx), dy);
            dx /= gcd;
            dy /= gcd;
            this.dx = dx;
            this.dy = dy;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object other) {
            if (!(other instanceof Line)) {
                return false;
            }
            Line another = (Line)other;
            return dx == another.dy && dy == another.dy;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return 31 * dx + dy;
        }
    }

    static int gcd(int a, int b) {
        return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure this works for vertical lines? By the way, you could get rid of the `Line` class by using the algorithm proposed by Pham

Comment: I'm sure it didn't work for vertical lines. :) I've edited my answer to use general form of line equation.

Comment: I've rewritten my solution almost complitly to make it more compact.

Comment: @AlexYakunin Yes, it works for parallel lines. Note that in each outermost iteration, `lines` are relative to point `a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Definition for a point.
 * struct Point {
 *     int x;
 *     int y;
 *     Point() : x(0), y(0) {}
 *     Point(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    int maxPoints(vector<Point> &points) {
        int n = points.size(); //number of the points
        if (n<=2){return n;}   
        vector<double> k; //vector to store the slops for one point with all the other points
        int res = 0;

        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){ // for each point in the 2d plane
            k.clear();
            int dup = 1; // number of the duplicates with currrent point
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++){ 
                if (i!=j){ // for every other point
                    if (points[i].x-points[j].x==0){ // if the slope is a vertical line
                        if (points[i].y-points[j].y==0){ // if the point j is the same as point i
                            dup++;  
                        }else{
                            k.push_back(99999); //store the vertical line to a specific slope
                        }
                    }else{ // if it is the regular slop between point i and j
                        k.push_back(10000*(points[i].y-points[j].y)/(points[i].x-points[j].x)); // store the slope
                    }
                }
            }

            sort(k.begin(),k.end()); //sort the slopes for counting

            int pp = 1; //number of points in the same line of the point i
            if (k.size()==0){pp=0;} 

            for (int jj=1;jj<k.size();jj++){ //count pp
                if (k[jj]==k[jj-1]){
                    pp++;
                }else{
                    if (pp+dup>res){res=pp+dup;} // res = pp + the number of duplicates
                    pp = 1;
                }
            }
            if (pp+dup>res){res = pp+dup;}
        }

        return res;
    }
};
```